# Hibernate CriteriaQuery. Как написать запрос?

Tags: java, hibernate

Как в Criteria написать такой запрос?

```
SELECT place_id FROM place_has_menu WHERE menu_id=?;
```

Если у нас класс Menu не знает ничего о классе Place, а в Place стоит связь с Menu OneToMany, которая генерирует собственно данную таблицу. Как же теперь написать этот запрос, используя метамодели?

**Update1**

```
@Entity
@Table
 public class Place {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "name")
private String name;

@JoinColumn(name="file")
private String file;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="places",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<PlaceType> placeTypes = new HashSet<PlaceType>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="placesToAdministrate", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserAccount> operators = new HashSet<UserAccount>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="place_has_menu",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "place_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")}
    )
private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();
```

В классе меню у меня нету никаких упоминаний об Плейс. Возможно тогда настроить эту связь в обратном порядке?

**Update2** Ответ:
Проблема в запросе была не потому, что проблемы были с доками гибернейта, а потому, что у меня были не правильно настроенные ентити, что и не позволяло получить данные с той таблицы, которая мне нужна была.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядеть это будет примерно так

```
var places = session.createCriteria(Place.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("menu_id", new Integer(2)))
    .list();
```

Comment: я использую entity manager, попробовал как-то подтянуть этот пример, но не получается. возможно вы знаете, как это сделать с em?

Comment: А что конкретно не получается, какие ошибки пишет?

Comment: Ну в данном случае этот запрос должен вернуть все `Place` у которых поле `menu_id` равно `2`, как-то так. У вас запросы, которые генерирует `Hibernate` выводятся куда-нибудь, например в консоль или output вашей IDE, что бы посмотреть толи что планировалось он сгенерировал?

Comment: получается, что у меня должен быть только один **Place** у которого **menu_id** равно **2**. Я пробовал сделать это джойнами, но так не получается, так как в таком случае мне нужно еще и **id** самого **Place** которое я как раз я хочу получить

Comment: другими словами, мне имея только айди `Menu` нужно получить из базы id `Place`а

Comment: Как вы написали, между  `Menu` и `Place`  у вас связь `Один ко Многим`, т.е. для одной записи `Menu` может быть несколько записей  `Place` (т.к. в `Place` есть внешний ключ на `Menu`). Если вы хотите получить по `ID` `Menu` - `ID` `Place`, то нужно понимать, что записей `Place` с указанным  `ID` может быть несколько и тогда какая из этих записей нужна конкретно вам остается не понятным.

Comment: Вы так и не написали, у вас запросы выводятся куда-нибудь, что бы можно было посмотреть толи было сгенерировано. И еще, как я понимаю, в результате выполнения запроса у вас просто получается пустая коллекция?

Comment: Возможно я тогда неправильно написал связи в энтити? Мне нужно, чтобы один Плейс имел несколько меню но не наоборот. Я сейчас обновлю вопрос, гляньте или у меня не правильно написано пожалуйста.
У меня результаты запросы никуда не выводятся так как у меня нету чего выводить. Я в принципе не могу написать этот запрос.

Comment: я обновил вопрос с энтити.

Comment: вы были правы. у меня не правильно настроенные ентити, теперь проблема решилась и не только  с этой таблицей. спасибо )